# how to set rect inside rect

Tags: iphone

I need to set Rectangle  inside CGRect.

how can i do that.

Answer (score 1):

CGRect is a structure . so use CGRect pointer .and access or set their element using -> tag.
hope it work.

Comment: i like to set small rect.. LIke this ----> \ [inside the rect..]      I am  Using where float linewidth=1.0f; CGRectMake(currentPoint.x-lineWidth,currentPoint.y-lineWidth,lineWidth,lineWidth*5)